# Programmable system on chip (SOC) pluggable on a host via PCIe

Tags: psoc, system-on-chip

Does anyone know a [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-on-module) which is put on a PCIe card, which has some flash memory, some RAM, JTAG support (or some kind of debugging support), some input ports like USB, perhaps support some output like via VGA or LVDS, just like this board: http://www.knjn.com/FPGA-PCIe.html but not for FPGA development, but for microprocessors, preferably x86.

Something similar [has been done](http://hardware.slashdot.org/hardware/08/10/02/2244229.shtml) in the past, but the link is dead, and it should have enough documentation and be hacker-friendly (and cheap, not more than 100-150 USD).

I will be writing the driver for the host system (linux), for inter-system communication, but the PCIe board itself should be pretty stand-alone (beside the operating system for the "guest OS" on the PCIe card which I will also have to write).

**Addendum**

(upon more research)

Sun used to have [SunPCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SunPCi), but those cards are hard to get. Besides, I want something more modern.

Thanks

Comment: I'm interested in the very same thing.  I want to team a couple of Linux SoCs together over PCIe and bring the PCIe bus out to add modules in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you're looking for, but thought it might be useful.

http://www.advantech.com.tw/products/PCE-5120/mod_B16C5C03-4498-49DD-BEF8-1ECF1890B322.aspx

From the site:

> LGA775 Core™ 2 Duo Processor Card with
>   PCI Express/VGA/Dual GbE LAN
>
> Complies
>   with PICMG 1.3 Supports LGA 775 Intel®
>   Core™ 2 Duo with 1066/800/533 MHz FSB
>   Supports dual-channel DDR2 533/667
>   SDRAM up to 4 GB One PCIe x16 and four
>   PCIe x1 links to backplane Dual
>   Gigabit Ethernet via two PCIe x1 ports
>   Onboard IPMI module (optional) Four
>   SATA2 channels with software RAID 0,
>   1, 5 and 10

Comment: Yes, I know about PICMG, but that is a for a two-segment pcie backplane. I need one with only one pcie slot, as you find in the regular computer industry, not on servers & co.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not what you're looking for, but I'd probably build a little board. Go with an Altera Cyclone IV GX FPGA (it's got a hardware PCIe core) and throw on some kind of CPU core, whether it be one of the NIOS ones (there's a free one) or something maybe from OpenEmbedded. The FPGA is about $60 and that includes the PCIe core and PHY. You could also toss in a SDRAM controller and a hardware USB interface (USB cores are expensive) and you'd be pretty close to what you're after, albeit with some design time.

Answer (score 1):

My own research, now four years later, turned up [iEi's line of PCIe cpu cards](http://www.ieiworld.com/product_groups/industrial/detail_list.aspx?keyword=PICOe-b&gid=00001000010000000001&cid=08141333914287007902&id=0C090521963186388827). No word on pricing yet, but some might fall into that range.

Edit: Three years later that link is dead - however if you search for IEI PCIe CPU card, you end up finding their [half-size SBC](https://www.ieiworld.com/en/product/items_by_cat.php?CA=1&cat23=1_2) cards, which are more or less the thing.

Comment: and that link is so dead...